# data validation: rejecting duplicates across multiple tabs in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, duplicates

I'll make the example simple for the question.  I have 2 tabs in google sheets:  Tab1 and Tab2.

Column A in Tab1 contains the following in rows 1-3...
david
chuck
steve

Column A in Tab2 contains the following in rows 1-3...
chris
scott
david

Once the name david appears in Column A of any tab (as it does in Tab2), it should be rejected if it is entered a second time in Column A of any tab (including the Column A of the tab in which it was originally entered.

I see several posts validating Column A on one tab.  But none validating across
multiple tabs, so I don't know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You might make a list of entered names, from both sheets, say in G1 of Tab2:

```
=query({'Tab1'!A:A;'Tab2'!A:A},"select Col1 where Col1 is not NULL")
```

and then apply a validation formula, eg for Tab1 of:

```
=countif('Tab2'!G:G,A1)<2
```